# How to check if a float is between multiple ranges in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, between

I'm trying to write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE ((long_expression BETWEEN -5 AND -2) OR 
       (long_expression BETWEEN 0 AND 2) OR 
       (long_expression BETWEEN 4 and 6))
```

Where `long_expression` is approximately equal to this:

```
(((t.s <#> (SELECT s FROM user WHERE user.user_id = $1)) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cluster_id) FROM cluster) * -1) + 1)
```

`t.s` and `s` are the `CUBE` datatypes and `<#>` is the indexed distance operator.

I could just repeat this long expression multiple times in the body, but this would be extremely verbose. An alternative might be to save it in a variable somehow (with a CTE?), but I think this might remove the possibility of using an index in the WHERE clause?

I also found `int4range` and `numrange`, but I don't believe they would work here either, because the distance operator returns float8's, not integer or numerics.

Comment: You could create a temporary table containing the long expression, and the index it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (long_expression)) v(x)
WHERE ((v.x BETWEEN -5 AND -2) OR 
       (v.x BETWEEN 0 AND 2) OR 
       (v.x BETWEEN 4 and 6)
      );
```

Of course, a CTE or subquery could be used as well; I like lateral joins because they are easy to express multiple expressions that depend on previous values.